# Where can I ask a question about HD TV boxes?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about what "hd tv boxes" do and which one I should pick from my cable  provider.

Is there a SE site suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Is that the whole question, or do you have something more prepared (research, references, specific concerns, etc.)?

Comment: I thought it unnecessary to post the whole question here. But it is about whether, for example, I should get a standard definition or high definition set top box from Rogers (Canada) - and what their respective resolutions are: 480p, 720p etc...

Comment: I would simply assume there was more to your question if it wasn't so common for people to post one liners, exactly the way your first paragraph reads. I don't think it's necessary to post the whole thing here, but without checking first - it would be irresponsible for anyone to say "Yeah, go ask on X". There is superuser, but shopping recommendations are off topic there, you'd have to rephrase the question to make it valuable to others. (and I think it must relate to computers in some way)

Comment: shopping.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

For anyone to answer this question correctly, you'd have to provide an overwhelming amount of information about your specific setup and needs. That would make your question "too localized" for Stack Exchange.

Alternatively, you could be less specific, but then you'd get less useful answers. Some would be based on answerers' personal experiences and all would involve some implicit assumptions. The question would devolve into a GTKY/poll post, which would be "not constructive."

So no, there is no suitable site in our network for your question.

Comment: Not [superuser](http://superuser.com/search?q=hd+tv+boxes), assuming there is more to the question than revealed in *this* post?

Comment: I don't know what goes on over at SU. The mods have been fairly receptive to my "this is a shopping/buying rec request," this is a poll" and "not constructive" flags (I don't have 3k) but in many cases they just leave comments or make small edits instead of closing.

Comment: @Madmartigan SuperUser only deals with things that interface with computers. If the question's just about TVs, it's off-topic there.

Comment: I suppose the hammer comes down fast on other SE sites due to the high traffic. I've never been quite able to fully understand the scope of superuser. @AnnaLear: Good point, I partially realized that in my [other comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125527/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-hd-tv-boxes/125531#comment338821_125527). I guess Yahoo! answers is the place for this one... or just call your cable provider and ask them.

Comment: @Madmartigan what Anna mentioned, plus the results that come up in Popular Demand's search link are related to connecting TVs to a GPU/computer